# Regular expression for date-like string shell

Tags: regex, shell

I'm trying to write a regular expression in `shell` for a date-like string but I'm having some difficulties. It should be formatted as `dd.mm.yyyy` where `dd` can be in range `0-99`, `mm` can be in range `0-99`, `year` is not limited

Regular expression should match these:

```
Hello we should meet 5.2.2010 after lunch.
Can we do it on 35.5.1900?
```

Regular expression shouldn't match these:

```
I'll be there 234.42.2010.
I'll come on Friday 4.2.20000. Maybe on 23.356.2011.
Can you play that with me on 4.2.?
```

So far, I've written this regular expression but it's not completely correct.

```
 grep -w "[0-99]\{1\}\.[0-99]\{1\}\.[0-9]\{4,\}"
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Whatever calendar you are following it's weird. Anyways [something like this](https://regex101.com/r/eJ3pK8/1) ?

Comment: actually you can't write `[0-99]`..It will be treated as `[0-9]` and `9`

Comment: It should be `[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{4}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `regex` is incorrect. The character class has predefined options like `[0-9]`, `[A-Z]` and `[a-z]`, but you are using `[0-99]`. So it will match any digit from `[0-9]` or the digit `9` itself.

The correct `regex` should be

```
[0-9]\{1,2\}\.[0-9]\{1,2\}\.[0-9]\{4\}
```

`grep -w` itself acts as word boundary. So there is no need of `\b`. From documentation

> Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that form whole
>                 words.  The test is that the matching substring must  either  be
>                 at  the  beginning  of  the  line,  or  preceded  by  a non-word
>                 constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the  end
>                 of  the  line  or  followed by a non-word constituent character.
>                 Word-constituent  characters  are  letters,  digits,   and   the
>                 underscore.

You can use the `-P` option for extended `PCRE` support as

```
grep -P -w "[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{4}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try: `[^0-9][0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{4}[^0-9]`

Note: you may have to pad string with a space on either side.

I would suggest using the modifier that makes you not have to escape `{`s (it might be `-E`).

## Explanation

- `[^0-9]` non-digit
- `[0-9]{1,2}\.` 1 or 2 digits and a period.
- `[0-9]{4}` 4 digits for year

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
>>> import re
>>> extract = lambda txt: re.findall(r"\b\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}\b", txt)
>>> print extract('Hello we should meet 5.2.2010 after lunch.')
['5.2.2010']
>>> print extract('Can we do it on 35.5.1900?')
['35.5.1900']
>>> print extract('Ill be there 234.42.2010.')
[]
>>> print extract('Ill come on Friday 4.2.20000. Maybe on 23.356.2011.')
[]
>>> print extract('Can you play that with me on 4.2.?')
[]
```